# How can I be sure to install the latest AMD/ATI graphics driver

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I currently have the graphic GPU as follows:

[url]http://us.toshiba.com/computers/laptops/satellite/P770/P775D-S7144[/url] no longer being sold but to help you determine the best driver for my system

PROCESSOR*
AMD Quad-Core A8-3520M Accelerated Processor

&

GRAPHICS ENGINE*
AMD Radeon™ HD 6620G

This processor is no slouch in Ubuntu 12.4. But I however want to keep my driver the best and newest possible since I'm now gaming with steam on Linux.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

and a shout out to Linus Torvalds for creating an awesome OS that makes computing fun again!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to watch this page :

[HOW TO ATI Drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

or if you like a video tutorial more, then go here:

[ati driver installation ubuntu 12.04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS9Nmet_sqQ)